# Seeking Oracle SQL procedure to read a LONG datatype column from a file

Tags: database, oracle, clob, lob

I have built the following procedure to read data into a CLOB (see code example below).
**Now I would like to have the same functionality to do that for a LONG column**.

I know that LONGs are deprecated in ORACLE but for my particular case it is neccessary to stay with LONG (for the moment).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my.p_update_proc (
        p_table_name IN VARCHAR2,
        p_column_name IN VARCHAR2,
        p_pattern IN VARCHAR2
)
as
l_sql varchar2(4000);

l_bfile   bfile := bfilename('MY_DIR',p_table_name||'.'||p_pattern||'.txt');
    l_data    clob;
    l_soffset NUMBER := 1;
    l_doffset NUMBER := 1;
    l_lang    NUMBER := 0;
    l_warn    NUMBER;
BEGIN
    DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (lob_loc => l_data,cache => TRUE,
                                 dur => DBMS_LOB.call);
    dbms_lob.fileopen( l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly );
    DBMS_LOB.loadclobfromfile(l_data, l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE,
           l_soffset, l_doffset, 0, l_lang, l_warn  );
    dbms_lob.fileclose(l_bfile);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);   -- to debug/trace your dynamic statement
    l_sql := 'update ' || p_table_name || ' set '|| p_column_name || '='
   || ':1' || ' where ' || p_column_name || ' like ' || '''' || p_pattern || ''
';
    execute immediate l_sql using l_data;
END; --Procedure
/
```

I'm aware that the constraint "like 'pattern'" doesn't work for LONGs and I could live with a modification such that I test for a different field in the table row for the identification of that row (and discard it later).

Changing a CLOB back into a LONG (by an ALTER TABLE MODIFY COLUMN) doesn't work either, so it's crucial to me that I find a way to fill the file content into a LONG into an already existing table.

Comment: So do you have a specific question?

Comment: I wrote:"Now I would like to have the same functionality to do that for a LONG column.". That's the question. How can I fill a LONG column from a file?